# Rails - how to make Geocoder "near" query with "where" condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I am working with the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and there is mentioned this snippet for searching records within a distance:

```
Venue.near('Omaha, NE, US', 20)
```

This is working well, but I would need to add another condition. This is the query I currently use:

```
   Car.where('car.status = ? AND listings.sold IS ?', 1, nil).includes(:images, :user)
```

And to this query I am trying to add the **near** call, like this:

```
Car.near('90013', 20).('car.status = ? AND listings.sold IS ?', 1, nil).includes(:images, :user)
```

But result of this query is just `nil`.

What is the correct way to combine **near** query with **where** condition?

Comment: append the near query to see what it does

Comment: Could it also be that you really just do not have any records that match this query?

Comment: Ok guys, I had in there a stupid bug. Anyway - there is one more thing - now the searching works almost perfectly, but if I set up a searching with ZIP Code **90013**, then are found records where the distance between ZIP Codes is < 20 miles, but not the ones with the exact ZIP Code - in this case are ignored records with ZIP Code ** 90013**. Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
nearest_location = @company.work_groups.where("level = 1 AND wg_active = 1 AND address IS NOT NULL AND address <> ''").near(employee_location, @company.miles, :order => :distance).first
```

Here is an example where I'm using the Geocoder gem and a where statement in the same line of code. Hope that it helps.